# Solution of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ x^u\cos(2\ln x)$ and $x^u\sin(2\ln x)$  are solutions to a linear second order differential equation.

What is the general solution? as their Wronskian is zero at only $x=0$

Could we say that  the solution of equation is either $x^u\cos(2\ln x)$ or $x^u\sin(2\ln x)$ at $x=0$ and $2x^{2u-1}$ for all other $x$?

Does interval matter, 
Is answer is same for all of the  intervals:

- $(-\pi/2 , \pi/2)$
- $(-\pi/2 , 0)$
- $(0, \pi/2)$
- $[-\pi/2 , \pi/2]$

Comment: I guess you forget to mention _some_ information about the differential equation? Linear? Second order? ...

Comment: You are right@mickep

Comment: Your solutions don't look like they are defined at $x=0$

Comment: Okay well! but what will be the general solution in the given intervals?@HowDoIMath

Comment: Let's start by writing the solutions the way that would make sense. A solution is a **function**, like $u(x)=x^a$. Sometimes you might prefer to use an _implicit function_, like $u(x)\cdot x=1$. The "=" part is important. Without it, there is no function. Where is your function?

Comment: $y= x^u\cos(2\ln x)$ and $y=x^u\sin(2\ln x)$  @Ivan Neretin

Comment: OK, then what is $u$? A constant?

Comment: Yes..@Ivan Neretin

Comment: Then what is the question? Any linear combination of two solutions is a solution, and that would be the general solution, unless these two are linearly dependent (which they are not).